# PHP - session_write_close() - Passing $_SESSION variables accross pages

Tags: php, session, redirect

My aim is to pass a message accross to another page without leaving the session open as this interferes with other scripts.

Lets say I have a form process on one page:

```
<?php

if ( process_form() ) {

    session_start();
    $_SESSION['success'] = 'The form has been saved.';
    session_write_close();
    header( 'Location: http://www.example.com/success.php' );
    exit();
    

} else {

    // Do something

}

?>
```

And on the second page I try to get the contents of the $_SESSION variable:

```
<?php
// success.php

var_dump( $_SESSION ); // 1

session_start();

var_dump( $_SESSION ); // 2

session_write_close();

var_dump( $_SESSION ); // 3

?>
```

The output is:

> 1. Undefined variable: _SESSION

> 2. array(1) { ["success"]=> string(24) "The form has been saved." }

> 3. array(1) { ["success"]=> string(24) "The form has been saved." }

Why can't we read the _SESSION variable without opening the session first?

Basically on the second page I only want to read data from the session and not leave it open, is this the best way?:

```
<?php
// success.php

session_start();
session_write_close();
echo $_SESSION['success'];

?>
```

The output is:

> The form has been saved.

Answer (score 1):

A session is stored and closed when a PHP script ends. In your first section of code that is at the `exit();`. Only after the output of the PHP script was sent to the browser will it react to the `header();` and load the other page. The session was closed already. This means that `session_write_close();`, in that piece of code serves no purpose, or, at least, doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Your question is:

> Why can't we read the _SESSION variable without opening the session
> first?

The most likely answer to that is that you haven't enabled the automatic session start feature.

See: [session.auto_start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start)

And you probably will not need to forcibly close the session with `session_write_close();` because this is done when PHP finishes the processing of the script.